# Shared class for child element in JAXB in different xmls/roots

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

In **JAXB** when using automatic class generation via **xjc** from *xsd* scheme.

**alpha.xsd**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="alpha">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="persons">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="person" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**beta.xml**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="country">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="class">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="person">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see there is `Person` element which is shared among these two schemes. What I would like to do is:

- generate classes using xjc in a way that `ObjectFactory` class is shared for both schema classes (the output classes will be in one package)
- not use nested static classes (with attribute `localScoping="toplevel"`)
- use `Person` class to bind with `/alpha/persons/person` as with `/country/class/person` so there are not two Person classes created

The purpose of this is unmarshalling one xml, applying business logic and creating another one as output where some elements (like `Person`) are same and shared for both xml files. The namespace will be the same for both files.

I would welcome if you can present me with complete .xjb bindings settings file. So far mine contains only:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" 
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

  <jxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

And of course I get name collision error as I do not know how to set binding compiler to see `Person` as the same entity/element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *namespace* of `person` from **A** will be equals *namespace* `person` from **B**, that *xjc* has to generate the correct classes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an external binding file to indicate that during class generation we wish to use our existing class for the complex type called Document.

**binding.xml**

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="beta.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='person']/complexType">
            <jxb:class ref="alpha.Person"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -b binding.xml beta.xsd
```