# How to skip complexType in JAXB bindings

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, complextype

I use JAXB bindings to generate java class from an existing xml schema. But I want to skip class generation for types that endswith "Old" or declare an "obsolete" attribute or contains undescore.

I try, in vain, to modify my JAXB bindings file but I don't know what node write to declare these types skipped...

```
<!-- skip old types -->
<!-- with ie:obsolete attribute -->
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="external/insee/*.xsd">
<jaxb:bindings node="//*[@ie:obsolete='true']">
    <!-- declare this type skipped -->
</jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
<!-- that endswith Old -->
<!-- that contains "_" underscore -->
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming none of the types you process reference these "skipped types", then you could use an external bindings file  to specify that they correspond to an existing class so that a new one won't be generated.  If these skipped types are referenced then references to this fake class will be brought into your model.

**binding.xml**

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="beta.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='person']/complexType">
            <jxb:class ref="com.FakeClass"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**Full Example**

- [Shared class for child element in JAXB in different xmls/roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837115/shared-class-for-child-element-in-jaxb-in-different-xmls-roots/19839837#19839837)

Comment: It works. Redirect to a Fake class is a good way to omit deprecated types. Thanks Blaise!